# Evaluation of limit of a quotient with a difference of square roots

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having trouble in evaluating this limits problem. The came up with the answer as $0$.

Evaluate 
$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{2}}{x - 2}$$

Comment: Hint: The bottom factors as $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2})$.  Or else: Multiply top and ottom by $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2}$. Don't multiply out the bottom.

Comment: another hint: $$x-2 = \sqrt{x}^2 - \sqrt{2}^2$$

Answer (score 5):

Note that

$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2}}{x-2} = \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2}}{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2})} = \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

This limit is the derivative  of the square root function at $x=2$, i.e. $\;\dfrac1{2\sqrt x}\Biggr\rvert_{x=2}=\dfrac1{2\sqrt 2}$

Comment: I absolutely like this way of thinking.  Wish more people would think like this. +1

Answer (score 0):

Notice, 
applying L-Hospital's rule as follows $$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt 2}{x-2}$$$$= \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}}{1}$$ $$= \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}}$$

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.